# Model.findByIdAndUpdate() with validate Author

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want update Category with validate Author

I have two models:

`Category: { id, title, description, author } //author contains userId`

`User: { id, name, categories } //categories contain categoryId.`

I want to check: Only author can update author's category, if you are not author, you can not update this category. How can I do it?

My code without `findByIdAndUpdate()`:

[image]

My code with `findByIdAndUpdate()`:

```
const update = async (id, updatedCategory, authorId) => {
    try {
        const { title, description } = updatedCategory
        const query = {
          ...(title && { title }),
          ...(description && { description }),
          date: Date.now(),
        }

        let category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(id, query, 
        (error, doc) => {
            return doc
        }

        if (!category) throw "Can not find category"
        // How to validate with authorId?
        return category
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make little modification in query. Instead of `findByIdAndUpdate` use `findOneAndUpdate`.

```
const update = async (id, updatedCategory, authorId) => {
    try {
        const { title, description } = updatedCategory
        const query = {
          ...(title && { title }),
          ...(description && { description }),
          date: Date.now(),
        }

        let category = await Category.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id, author:authorId}, query, 
        (error, doc) => {
            return doc
        }

        if (!category) throw "Can not find category"
        // How to validate with authorId?
        return category
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```